# Git error when pushing: object 15abe3addde5ad5f7d25e8f0f220d2e9faf3cb22:contains entries pointing to null

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

I'm not sure how I have got myself into this mess. But I am running into `error: object 15abe3addde5ad5f7d25e8f0f220d2e9faf3cb22:contains entries pointing to null` when trying to push my repository to GitHub. The full push:

```
[ashinn@puppet1 puppet]$ git push
Counting objects: 27, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 5.67 KiB, done.
Total 16 (delta 6), reused 14 (delta 4)
error: object 15abe3addde5ad5f7d25e8f0f220d2e9faf3cb22:contains entries pointing to null sha1
fatal: Error in object
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To git@github.com:andyshinn/puppet.git
 ! [remote rejected] ganglia -> ganglia (unpacker error)
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:andyshinn/puppet.git'
Everything up-to-date
```

Git ls-tree shows that my sudo module is a null sha1:

```
[ashinn@puppet1 puppet]$ git ls-tree 15abe3addde5ad5f7d25e8f0f220d2e9faf3cb22
...
160000 commit 2cc9d02b3cf27d6a06d85612c03710aa0d90149c  ssh
160000 commit 6961179007dce76d7fb9bd1fc361273acb4129a7  stdlib
160000 commit 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  sudo
040000 tree 2bd16a8fab440081a876f64d720b5b4d9d119bc9    sysctl
040000 tree 01439b5a20363dccdf3f7103aab701fa7f4b3cd9    template
...
```

The listed `ssh`, `stdlib`, and `sudo` are submodules of external git repos. Folders `sysctl` and `template` are folders in the repo.

I have tried removing the module and re-adding it and can't seem to push any commit now. I've done some searching and found little on the error. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: looks like your repo is screwed up, try to fsck or I hope you have a backup or another clone to start over

Comment: When I run  `git fsck --full` it doesn't return anything. I assume there is nothing to fsck.

Comment: It's hosted on GitHub. Am I suppose to just wipe it, create a new one, and push my current repo? Are you saying the destination is corrupt or the local copy?

Comment: I would take a guess and say the local repo is broken, but see my answer for the complete troubleshooting process.

Comment: So it looks like the local repo is broken. Any way to repair the tree? Google doesn't come up with much information on the git tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to finally solve this issue. Here is what I did to solve it:

In article https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data there is a heading for **Purge the file from your repo**. I following their example for removing the Rakefile but used the problematic folder instead:

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch modules/sudo'  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Since the problematic tree was a folder I added `-r` to the command. The result was a cleanup of all the commits for the sudo modiles and thus, object *15abe3addde5ad5f7d25e8f0f220d2e9faf3cb22* disappeared! After a commit of the changes, the push was successful. I was able to later re-add the broken module without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the github repo (bare) to another local directory.
Then add this as a remote and try to push to that remote.
If this fails, then your problem is probably local.
(This would be my guess)

If not, I would still try to clone your "working repo" and try pushing from that clone to the local remote you added previously.

If this doesn't help, you either have rename/backup your github repo and create a new one or have to contact the github support.

Comment: I'll accept this as it contained what I ultimately had to do, which was kill the GitHub repo and create it again and then push to it. It was a problem on the GitHub remote. I contacted GitHub support but didn't get very far with them. It was easiest just to blow it away and create it again.

Comment: I ran into this error again and tried this. But the same issue happens. the sudo commit has a null sha1. I killed the existing GitHub repo and tried to push to a new remote and get the same issue. Is it possible to repair the local repo?