# Git - nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1

Tags: git

I'm trying to deploy an app and I get a error. Following research pointed me here:

```
warning in tree f148931b374ad1aa9748b8f91bd48fcb44fb73b0: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree f148931b374ad1aa9748b8f91bd48fcb44fb73b0
              to    blob 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
missing blob 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183847/how-to-remove-an-entry-with-null-sha1-in-a-git-tree) but the commands do nothing on terminal they just sit there.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove an entry with null sha1 in a Git tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183847/how-to-remove-an-entry-with-null-sha1-in-a-git-tree)

Answer (score 3):

You could try, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14739771/6309), to remove the commit with the null sha1, using git filter-branch

```
git ls-tree f148931b374ad1aa9748b8f91bd48fcb44fb73b0
<an element>
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <an element path>'  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Replace `<an element path>` by the path relative to the root folder of the repo of the element returned by `git ls-tree`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, these days [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is the [officially recommended alternative](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning) to `git filter-branch`, which is newer, safer and faster.

#### Tl;dr

First use `git ls-tree --full-name <treeish>` to find the path of the bad object(s)/file(s), then use `git filter-repo --invert-paths` to rewrite the history commits and remove the bad file(s).

#### Example usage of `git filter-repo` for removing objects

```sh
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path '<path-to-file1>' --path '<path-to-file2>`
```

Or use option `--path-glob`, or `--path-regex` to match files with a pattern:

```sh
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path-glob '<glob>` --path-regex '<regex>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to setup a project to use submodules. Getting rid of the submodules fixed the error.